# Vertical inline-block?

Tags: inline, css, direction

Currently I have something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XgCDb/). The "Page" and "Row" elements are created dynamically using javascript.

The problem rises when there are multiple Pages, and a Row in the Page 1 is deleted, for [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mxpVc/2/). The empty space should be filled by the element that is below, if the empty space is at the end of the page, then the first element of the next page should fill the empty space, and so on. At the end it should look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DHXKU/1/).

I can solve this rearranging/recreating the entire `PageCont`.

Is there a way I can achieve this using pure CSS? So the rearranging would be handled by the rendering engine of the browser.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HatvF/18/) inline-block but with vertical direction.

Any help is highly apreciated.

​HTML:

```
<div class="PageCont">
    <div class="Page">
        <div class="Row">1</div>
        <div class="Row">2</div>
        <div class="Row">3</div>
        <div class="Row">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Page">
        <div class="Row">5</div>
        <div class="Row">6</div>
        <div class="Row">7</div>
        <div class="Row">8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Page">
        <div class="Row">9</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.PageCont
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 350px;    

    border:2px solid red
}

.Page
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}

.Row
{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;

    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

​

Comment: How do you want them to be rearranged? Do you want every square to dynamically change their numbers and move? Pretty sure `float` would be a way of going about it but if we are talking about changing the numbers, I believe that requires some javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation could be successfully performed trivially if it included horizontal wrapping, with plain simple CSS. However since this case involves vertical wrapping javascript be necessary with your current implementation. If you were to use columns you wouldn't need the javascript and CSS is all that's needed.
Here is a fiddle where I've implemented it http://jsfiddle.net/eQvaZ/

The HTML is as follows:

```
<body>
    <div class="pageCont">
        <div  class="Row">C1</div>
        <div class="Row">C2</div>
        <div  class="Row" id="to-remove">C3</div>
        <div  class="Row">C4</div>
        <div  class="Row">C5</div>
        <div  class="Row">C6</div>
        <div  class="Row">C7</div>
    </div>
    <div>Removing C3 in 5 seconds...</div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
.pageCont{
    column-count:2;
    column-rule:0px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-rule: 0px;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-rule: 0px;
    padding:10px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 200px;
    border:2px solid red
 }

.Row {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    margin-bottom:10px;
 }
```

The bit of JavaScript to remove an item:

```
setTimeout( function(){
var to_remove = document.getElementById('to-remove');
to_remove.parentNode.removeChild(to_remove);
}, 5000);
```

Let me know if you have any questions regarding this implementation.

Comment: no problem, just a small reminder, this code uses html5 and thus will be supported by modern browsers, the older ones will not vertically wrap to form multiple columns.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! But the application is intended to work under IE8.

Comment: In that case you would have to use your previous implementation with a little bit of javascript, do you mind that?